# Verify Steam ID ownership in NET Core + React App

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core, steam, steam-web-api

I am using React as a frontend and .NET Core Web Api as a backend. All communication is through the HTTP between the two servers.

I would like to have "Sign in through steam" button on my page, when clicked redirected to steam website for login and just want to get the steam ID back to verify that they own the account. That's it.

What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: I am not trying to sign my users in through steam, I just want to get their steam_id's back, my users will already be signed in through my own user portal, using this button I just attach their steam id's to their accounts

Answer (score 0):

You have to call steam API from your Core Web API using HttpClient().

Refer to : https://steamcommunity.com/dev